# How many 3-digit numbers which are divisible by 13 and have 5 in the middle digit

Tags: combinatorics

> How many three-digits numbers are there which are divisible by $13$ and have $5$ as the middle digit.

So the number satisfying the above condition would be in the form of $x5y$ where $x,y \in (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)$

$\therefore$ number in expanded form would be $100x + 50 +y$

**My question is**

**How many such numbers exist ?**

Answer (score 2):

Note that 104 and 52 are multiples of 13.  Then

$$100x + 50 + y = (104-4)x+ (52-2) + y = 104x + 52 +(y-2-4x).$$

So you need $y-2-4x$ to be a multiple of 13.  That is, you need $y\equiv 2+4x  \pmod{13}.$  So plug each possible value of $x$ into the congruence and see if there is a solution for $y$ in the range needed.  There are at most, then $9$ solutions.

Comment: But the other answer say $7$ numbers

Comment: "At most 9" means that there are 9 or fewer solutions.  7, you may note, is fewer than 9.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$100x+50+y\equiv0\iff y\equiv2+4x\pmod{13}$$

$x\equiv1\implies y\equiv6\pmod{13}$

$x\equiv9\implies y\equiv12>10$ hence is not allowed

All we need to ensure $0\le y<10$

Answer (score 0):

Answer: $7$ numbers.

There are $90$ $3$-digit numbers satisfying the condition that $5$ is the middle number.

They are in groups of $10$ numbers as follows:

$$150–159,250–259, \ldots,950–959$$

Now there is *at most* one number in each group which is divisible by $13$ which is known by the fact that one number in a group of $13$ consecutive numbers will be divisible by $13$.

So consider each group and take suitable no in one's place to get the required $3$ digit numbers.

1) $15\_$
$156$ is the required no in this group.

2) $25\_$
No number is divisible by $13$.

3) $35\_$
$351$ is the required no in this group.

4) $45\_$
$455$ is the required no in this group.

5) $55\_$
$559$ is the required no in this group.

6) $65\_$
$650$ is the required no in this group.

7) $75\_$
$754$ is the required no in this group.

8) $85\_$
$858$ is the required no in this group.

9) $95\_$
no number is divisible by $13$.